# how to appeand class to parent element on current page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, parent

**UPDATE**

I have printed the page's pathname on to the page and discovered it is not reading past the requests.

```
let path = document.querySelector("#path");
path.innerHTML = "Page pathname is: " + location.pathname;
```

so for link `private.php?folderid=0` the pathname is `private.php` discovering this did disappoint me, but the topic of this question remains the same.

**END UPDATE**

I am trying to add a class to the parent element if if a link is the current page.

My links are structured in the following way:

```
<li role="presentation" class="pane-link pane-folder $navclass[deletedthreads]" nowrap="nowrap">
  <a class="smallfont" href="moderation.php?$session[sessionurl]do=viewthreads&amp;type=deleted">$vbphrase[threads]</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" class="pane-link pane-folder $navclass[deletedposts]" nowrap="nowrap">
  <a class="smallfont" href="moderation.php?$session[sessionurl]do=viewposts&amp;type=deleted">$vbphrase[posts]</a>
</li>
```

There are many more but they all share the class `pane-link`

The JS is were I am struggling, I am trying to add the class `active` to the `li` element if the current page is the page of the link.

The method I was attempting `location.pathname` I discovered would not read my full link. (I believe)

This is what I did have (not working)

```
if("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']") {
  $("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").parent().addClass("active");
}
```

**NOTE** Not all links in my list contain variables like in the example above.  Some links are as simple as `private.php?do=newpm` I'm not sure if having the variables in the links are effecting the Javascript location.

I want to know, how can I add a class to my `li` if my link is the current page?

Comment: Quick question; is the location.pathname what you expect it to be?

Comment: Not all links contain variables like in my example, but I'm not sure honestly.  From everything I have been searching this was the way to do what I was after, I'm just not implementing it correctly. I will update the OP with this information as well

Comment: If you're not sure what you're receiving as "input" use console.log - just a hint, but it might help

Comment: Your `if()` statement doesn't make sense. `if(StringWithLength)` will always be truthy

Comment: how is my if statement always true? its saying if a link is the link to the page currently on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.href` : `http://yourwebsite.com/private.php?folderid=0`

`location.origin` : `http://yourwebsite.com/`

`location.pathname` : `private.php`

So to simply get the pathname with params you can use `.replace`

```
<script>
    var loc = location.href.replace(location.origin , '');  
    console.log(location);
</script>
```

To check for element use `.length`

```
<script>
   if($(element).length){
   }
</script>
```

So both code combined should looks like this

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var loc = location.href.replace(location.origin , '');  
        console.log(loc);
       if($("a.smallfond[href*='"+loc+"']").length){
          $("a.smallfond[href*='"+loc+"']").parent().addClass('active');
       }
     }
</script>
```

Note: be sure the jquery library is included

Answer (score 0):

I am using `location.pathname` where I should be using `window.location` replacing just that gave me my desired outcome.

My end script became:

```
if("a[href*='" + window.location + "']") {
  $("a[href*='" + window.location + "']").parent().addClass("active");
}
```